# MySQL select distinct and max with all columns

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a db table: pf_pqs:

```
+----------+------+--------+-------+---------+
|    onr   | prSh | liteNr | seqNr | planQty |
+----------+------+--------+-------+---------+
| 10347006 | HEG  |    1   |    0  |   5     |
| 10347006 | TEH  |    1   |    1  |   5     |
| 10347006 | KAR  |    1   |    2  |   5     |
| 10347006 | LEN  |    1   |    3  |   5     |
| 10347006 | HEG  |    2   |    0  |   5     |
| 10347006 | LEN  |    2   |    1  |   5     |
| 10347006 | HEG  |    3   |    0  |   5     |
| 10347006 | TEH  |    3   |    1  |   5     |
| 10347006 | KAR  |    3   |    2  |   5     |
| 10347006 | LEN  |    3   |    3  |   5     |
```

Result must include biggest `seqNr` in every `liteNr` and all other corresponding fields correctly; like this:

```
+----------+------+--------+-------+---------+
|    onr   | prSh | liteNr | seqNr | planQty |
+----------+------+--------+-------+---------+
| 10347006 | LEN  |    1   |    3  |   5     |
| 10347006 | LEN  |    2   |    1  |   5     |
| 10347006 | LEN  |    3   |    3  |   5     |
```

I tried different queries with joins and grouping but no luck so far :(.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you only interested on seqNr and liteNr?

Comment: *"Result must include biggest `seqNr` in every `liteNr` and all other corresponding fields "* -- `GROUP BY` doesn't help here. You want to return rows from the table but `GROUP BY` doesn't return rows from the table. It **generates** values using the values from the table.

Comment: Group By helps you find the biggest seqNr for every liteNr. Then join those values back in the table to get the corresponding rows. Have tou tried the posted code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming then liteNr and seqNr do not repeat themselfs, something like this should work:

```
SELECT
     p1.onr, 
     p1.prSh, 
     p1.liteNr, 
     p1.seqNr, 
     p1.planQty
FROM
    pf_pqs p1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            liteNr,
            MAX(seqNr) AS seqNr 
        FROM
            pf_pqs
        GROUP BY
            liteNr  
    ) p2 ON
    p2.liteNr = p1.liteNr
    AND p2.seqNr = p1.seqNr
```

Comment: this seem to work, when i have only one onr value (10347006), but i also need select onr field. in reality i have thousands different onr values. Where do i put WHERE clause? WHERE onr=10347006

Comment: If you want to filter the results, for only one onr value, the where should be place in the inner select.

Comment: added SELECT onr to inner select and p2.onr=p1.onr at the end, now got correct result. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Correct query

```
SELECT
         p1.onr, 
         p1.prSh, 
         p1.liteNr, 
         p1.seqNr, 
         p1.planQty
    FROM
        pf_pqs p1
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                onr,
                liteNr,
                MAX(seqNr) AS seqNr 
            FROM
                pf_pqs
            GROUP BY
                liteNr  
        ) p2 ON
        p2.liteNr = p1.liteNr
        AND p2.seqNr = p1.seqNr
        AND p2.onr=p1.onr
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to select the maximum seqNr per liteNr which you can do by `SELECT liteNr, MAX(seqNr) ... GROUP BY liteNr`. Then you join this back with the table using `ON a.liteNr = b.liteNr AND a.seqNr = b.seqNr`. Queries like this require two steps. With the first query you query the maximum seqNrs per liteNr but this will only give you two columns `(liteNr, seqNrMax)` which you now have to look up again in the original table which you can do with a join or a nested select.

However, if you have two rows with a max seqNr then your final result may contain duplicates which you need to be aware of.

```
mysql> SELECT `NAME`, `PRICE`, 
          `VENDOR` 
   FROM `PRODUCTS` `P1` 
   WHERE `P1`.`PRICE` = (
    SELECT MIN(`PRICE`) 
    FROM `PRODUCTS` `P2` 
    WHERE `P2`.`NAME` = `P1`.`NAME`);


mysql> SELECT `P1`.`NAME`, `N` AS `PRICE`, 
          `P1`.VENDOR
   FROM `PRODUCTS` `P1` 
   JOIN ( 
    SELECT `NAME`, MIN(`PRICE`) AS `N` 
    FROM `PRODUCTS` `P2` 
    GROUP BY `NAME`) `P2` 
   ON `P1`.`NAME` = `P2`.`NAME`
   WHERE `P1`.`PRICE` = `N`;
```

Are the two most common ways to do these kind of queries but there are like at least three additional other ways to do it.